# Does scala has a class for lazy thunks that are evaluated once or never?

Tags: lazy-evaluation, scaladoc, thunk

Something as simple

```
class Thunk[+A](body: => A) {
  lazy val result: A = body;
}
```

Is it defined somewhere?

Or perhaps a slightly more sohpisticated

```
class Thunk[+A](body: => A) {
  private[this] var evaluatedInternal = false;

  lazy val result: A = {
    evaluatedInternal = true;
    body;
  }

  def evaluated: Boolean = evaluatedInternal;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are classes [`Name`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Name.scala) and `Need` in Scala that provide just that functionality. See also Scalaz [Issue #427](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/issues/427).